# C++ char conversion

Tags: c++, windows, char

I googled it for 2 hours now, and i can't find an answer for my problem: i need to get a registry `REG_SZ` value and pass it to a `char*`.

```
char host_val[1024];
DWORD hostVal_size = 1024;
char* hostName;
DWORD dwType = REG_SZ;

RegOpenKeyEx(//no problem here);
if( RegQueryValueEx( hKey, TEXT("HostName"), 0, &dwType, (LPBYTE)&host_val, &hostVal_size ) == ERROR_SUCCESS )
{
      //hostName = host_val; 
}
```

How should i do this conversion `hostName = host_val`?

Comment: What's the problem exactly? to convert char array of fixed lenth to char *?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall, yes, the conversion is my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're compiling with Unicode you're copying a Unicode string (that is possibly NOT terminated) into a narrow char buffer. the first character in the unicode string will be 0x3100 (accounting for the endianness on your machine, which is likely little-endian, and the fact that you said the IP address is 192....)

That value stuffed into the char[] array will report back as a single-char-null-terminated string. You have two options.

1. Use RegQueryValueExA, everything else stays the same, or
2. Change your char[] array to a wchar_t[] array, do what you're currently doing, then convert to narrow using WideCharToMultiByte(docs are in the SDK).

For obvious reasons, I'd take the former of those two options.

Comment: if i use `RegQueryValueExA` i get an `error C2664: 'RegQueryValueExA' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const wchar_t [9]' to 'LPCSTR'`

Comment: Take out the TEXT() macro wrapper, for your string literals on that call.

Answer (score 4):

The resulting `host_val` is a [possibly non-null-terminated string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (see "Remarks"), so you should copy it to a newly allocated string with `memcpy`, and ensure it's null-terminated:

```
hostName = new char[hostVal_size + 1];
// host_val may or may not be null-terminated
memcpy(hostName, host_val, hostVal_size);
hostName[hostVal_size] = '\0';
```

You will need to `delete[]` the `hostName` later.

Comment: the value in my registry is an IP address, say, `192.168.1.219`. Using `RegQueryValueEx` that value is passed to `host_val`, but after using your code all that is copied to `hostName` is `1`.

Answer (score 3):

use the ANSI version of the function

```
RegQueryValueExA
```

that way you don't need to convert.